# Issue with MATLAB app designer playing sounds

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

I am trying to play a sound when I press a button using MATLAB app designer 2021a; I use the following lines

```
    [x, fs] = audioread('abc.wav');
    freq = 2 * fs;  
    player = audioplayer(x, freq); 
    play(player);
```

But I don't get the audio. However, when I copy the same lines in the command box, I get the audio after I wrote the following lines there:

```
   restoredefaultpath
    rehash toolboxcache
    savepath
```

Can someone please tell me how I can play using app designer cause the lines above create lag there?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing a similar issue, I used

```
sound(x,freq);
```

instead of

```
player = audioplayer(x, freq); 
play(player);
```

Comment: you can also define 'player' as a public property in the app and audioplayer will work fine